Histogram of angular data without edge aliasing?
I'm sampling angles which are known to have a certain density in $(-\pi,\pi)$ range (background). Using Histogram to visualize it creates an aliasing effect around the edges. Is there a nice way around this?
IE, you can see a mismatch at the edges of the graph, which I suspect is connected to how Mathematica calculates densities:

negateFirstRow[A_] := {-A[[1, All]]}~Join~A[[2 ;;, All]];
sampleO[n_] := RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]];
sampleSO[n_] := 
  With[{mat = sampleO@n}, If[Det[mat] > 0, mat, negateFirstRow@mat]];

n = 4;
numSamples = 10000;
label = StringForm["Eigenvalues of SO(``)", n];
angles = Arg /@ Flatten[Table[Eigenvalues@sampleSO@n, {numSamples}]];
observedPlot = 
  Histogram[angles, Automatic, PDF, PlotLabel -> label, 
   AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}];
predictedPlot = 
  Plot[(Cos[2 t] + 2)/(4 Pi), {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 3/(4 Pi)}, 
   PlotLegends -> {TraditionalForm[(Cos[2 t] + 2)/(4 Pi)]}];
Show[observedPlot, predictedPlot]


Don't use Automatic for the bin width specification. Use {Pi/n}, e.g., {Pi/15}

You could periodically extend the data (e.g. add +-2Pi to each sample) then limit the plot range to +-Pi.  You'd need to adjust the density, somehow.

Perhaps looking at the SmoothHistogram of the data may be nice too since you are comparing it to a continuous underlying density function?

@BobHanlon's recipe fixes aliasing

If you must use a histogram, then another alternative similar to @BobHanlon 's suggestion is to increase the number of samples (numSamples = 100000;) and instead of Automatic for the bin width use {Table[p, {p, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100}]}.

This comment has nothing to do with your specific question concerning the histogram but I'm wondering about the generation of the samples.  For even values of n pairs of angles are generated (one negative and one positive).  So because that's just duplicate information, shouldn't just the positive (or negative) values be considered?  Otherwise you're artificially doubling the sample size.

Another variant of @BobHanlon 's suggestion:  Replace Automatic with {-\[Pi], \[Pi], Automatic} or {-\[Pi], \[Pi], "FreedmanDiaconis"} as you know the boundaries.  That gives you at least an initial binwidth without having to give a specific value.

Get into the 21st century and ditch the 19th century histogram.  (Yes, I'm being a bit sarcastic and not as constructive as the good comments by @mikado and @ydd.)
Replace observedPlot with the following:
data = Join[angles, angles - 2 \[Pi], angles + 2 \[Pi]];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 0.1];
observedPlot = Plot[3 PDF[skd, arg], {arg, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.015]}},
   PlotLabel -> label, AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {0, Automatic}},
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red}, {"Estimated density"}]];

and obtain

The "modified" data is a clone of the original data in that copies of the data were placed to the left and right of the original data followed by a nonparametric density estimate using SmoothKernelDistribution.  Because the "modified" data includes 3 times the original number of data points, we need to multiply by 3 the resulting density from SmoothKernelDistribution.
Note that both SmoothKernelDistribution and SmoothHistogram have a "Bounded" option.  However, that option mirrors the data on each side of the boundaries (at $-\pi$ and $\pi$) which is not what you want in this case.  That mirroring is different from the modification shown above.
If you must use a histogram, then here is a slight variant of the suggestion by @BobHanlon:
numSamples = 1000000; (* As you are in complete control of the sample size *)
angles = Arg /@ Flatten[Table[Eigenvalues@sampleSO@n, {numSamples}]];
observedPlot = 
  Histogram[angles, {Table[p, {p, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100}]}, PDF,
   PlotLabel -> label, AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}];

with the result being

